# Perl: Separating a string to element of array with common character?

Tags: arrays, regex, string, perl, expression

So lets say I have a string `aaataagggggcccccccccccaa`. How can I break this string into elements of just a common letter?

For example I want the array to look like this:

```
Element 1: 'aaa'
Element 2: 't'
Element 3: 'aa'
Element 4: 'ggggg'
Element 5: 'cccccccccc'
Element 6: 'aa'
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [Backreferences](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Backreferences) to match repeated characters:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my $string = 'aaataagggggcccccccccccaa';
my @arry;

while ( $string =~ /((.)\2*)/g ) {
    push @arry, $1;
}

use Data::Dump;
dd @arry;
```

**Outputs:**

```
("aaa", "t", "aa", "ggggg", "ccccccccccc", "aa")
```

Comment: @ysth There ya go! `:)`